# Download a list of Objects in a bucket from S3

Tags: php, javascript, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on Amazon S3 which contains hundreds of objects. 
I have a web page that lists out all these objects and has a download object link in html.

This all works as expected and I can download each object individually.

How would it be possible to provide a checkbox next to each link, which allowed a group of objects to be selected and then only those objects downloaded?

So to be clear, if I chose items 1, 2, and 7 - and clicked a download link - only those object would be downloaded. This could be a zip file or one at a time although I have no idea how this would work.

I am capable of coding this up, but I am struggling to thing HOW it would work - so process descriptions are welcome. I could consider python or ruby although the web app is PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is a hard problem to solve.

S3 does not allow any 'in place' manipulation of files, so you cannot zip them up into a single download. In the browser, you a stuck with downloading one url at a time. Of course, there's nothing stopping the user queuing up downloads manually using a download manager, but there is nothing you can do to help with this.

So you are left with a server side solution. You'll need to download the files from S3 to a server and zip them up before delivering the zip to the client. Unfortunately, depending on the number and size of files, this'll probably take so time, so you need a notification system to let the user know when their file is ready.

Also, unless your server is running on EC2, you might be paying twice for bandwidth charges. S3 to your server and then your server to the client.

Comment: Thanks Geoff. I had the same thoughts. Its turning into a much more complicated solution than anticipated.